# Easier way to calculate triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So I had to calculate an integral that goes like that
$$\iiint\  \frac{x^2}4+y^2 dxdydz$$
where the area is

$$\frac{x^2}4+y^2=1$$ $$z=0$$ $$z=x+2y+5$$

I actually **solved** this triple integral and my answer is $\mathbf{5}\pi$. I made it in two ways:

1. I described the area as $$-2<x<2$$ $$-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}<y<\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}$$ $$0<z<x+2y+5$$
2. And using polar form where I calculated ellipse's radius as $0<r<\frac{2}{\sqrt{4\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi}}$ and the change of '$z$' as $0<z<\cos\phi r+2\sin\phi r +5$ where $ 0<\phi<2\pi $

But I feel like I may overcomplicate this?
Is there a way to solve this triple integral easier/faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify the integral with $x=2u$, $y=v$ and $z=2w$
$$I=\iiint \frac{x^2}4+y^2 \ dxdydz
= 4\iiint u^2+v^2 \ dudvdw
$$
with the integration region $u^2+v^2=1$, $w=0$ and $w=u+v+\frac52$. Then, in cylindrical coordinates
\begin{align}
I=& \ 4\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_0^{r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta )+\frac52}r^3 dw dr d\theta\\
=& \ 4\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r^4(\cos\theta+\sin\theta )+\frac52 r^3 dr d\theta=5\pi
\end{align}

Comment: That's it, simpler, easier and faster. Thank you so much. However i have one question, why is there 4 before integrals?

Comment: @PiotrWj that is from the change of variables

Comment: @layabout I'm afraid i don't see this. We have $\frac{4u^2}4 + v^2$ = $u^2+v^2$ don't we?

Comment: If you recall from one variable calculus that if we make a substitution $2u = x$ we must have $2du = dx$ and so (basically) we get $2\int f(u) du = \int f(x) dx$. A similar thing (conceptually) is happening here, as well as when you reparameterize into spherical or cylindrical coordinates. Look into [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables).